# Own stellar horizon is not showing data prior to own instance launch date

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, docker

I run a stellar node using the docker quickstart image and due to some syncing error the underlying ec2 instance was terminated and restarted on 2018-12-28T10:45:19Z, state of core is `Synced`.

However, if I query `/accounts/{account_id}/trades` on the local horizon instance I only get trades after that restarting date.

When I run `/metrics` it shows a very recent elder_ledger (around that time horizon was launched). When i run horizon db backfill i get:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.glob..func1(0x13b1600, 0x1414450, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/stellar/go/services/horizon/db.go:35 +0x18d
github.com/stellar/go/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x13b1600, 0x1414450, 0x0, 0x0, 0x13b1600, 0x1414450)
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/stellar/go/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:603 +0x241
github.com/stellar/go/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc0000e5440, 0xc000028118, 0x0, 0xc000133f70)
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/stellar/go/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:689 +0x2cc
github.com/stellar/go/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0xc0000e5440, 0xc000133f88, 0xc000028118)
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/stellar/go/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:648 +0x2b
main.main()
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/stellar/go/services/horizon/main.go:23 +0x2d
```

How can I sync my horizon to show stuff prior to launching the node?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running horizon with the ingest command manually?

So it would be something like:

`horizon --ingest=true`

Or if that complains about the stellar core url and DB not being set, something like:

`horizon --stellar-core-url=http://localhost:11626 --stellar-core-db-url=postgres://YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE@localhost/core --db-url=postgres://stellar:YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE@localhost/horizon --ingest=true`

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the following steps from the administrator's guide:

- [Correct the gaps in the database following these steps](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/admin.md#correcting-gaps-in-historical-data)
- [Reingest any ledgers you might want to refresh in the db](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/admin.md#reingesting-ledgers)
- [Make sure you're ingesting new data, and do any backfills as necessary](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/admin.md#ingesting-live-stellar-core-data)

The full guide is [on Github](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/admin.md) — feel free to comment with anything that doesn't work out here.